# Why is my Synology NAS always caching data even when nothing new has been written?

Tags: ssd, nas, cache, synology-diskstation

I have a Synology NAS DS720+ with two 4To HDD and two 250Go SSD for read/write cache. Most of the time, the NAS is not used and nothing is read or written on it. Yet it makes noise all the time because it is caching data into the SSD. I don't understand why: nothing new is written on the disks and the constant noise (a ~1Hz click from the Read/Write head) is super annoying.

Is there a configuration I am missing ? What is being written on the SSD ? In the worst case, I would at least be able to automatically disable SSD caching on specific time slots but I could not find anything like that on the DSM.

Thanks for your help

[Screenshot of the DSM task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDwSv.png)

*The "writeback" process is always running, and always writing between 100Ko/s and 700Ko/s. It's the only process that uses the disks even when I'm not using the NAS at all. When I permanently disable SSD cache, the noise goes away.*

Comment: This is a question to the NAS manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to trace any I/O on the disks from the computer, in case
the cause is some program that's constantly accessing the disk.

The likelier explanation that this is caused by the firmware of
the disks and is entirely normal, but unstoppable.

This sound may be attributed perhaps to PWL, which stands for
"Preventive Wear Leveling". It's a periodic head sweep to distribute
lubricant and prevent wear in a particular place if lubricant were to
build up in one spot.
The firmware of WD disks is especially well-known for it.

NAS drives especially are built to do maintenance and reorganizing
the data for faster retrieval. Their main purpose is performance, after all.

See the following thread to see that you are not alone:
[My Synology has been doing this sound/noise every few seconds (except when hibernating) since it was setup 3 days ago. Is it normal?](https://www.reddit.com/r/synology/comments/ktsino/my_synology_has_been_doing_this_soundnoise_every/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, actually I'm pretty sure the program that is accessing the disk is the one responsible for SSD caching (writeback process as shown in the screenshot). I'm looking for ways to configure the behaviour of this program such as setting time slots, or even excluding some paths that don't need SSD cache (Time Machine backups for instance).